# locked lumia 625 locked by microsoft account

Tags: outlook

I found my lost Lumia 625 after locking it by a code from my Microsoft account. Now i can not use the code on my phone. There is a crying emoji on the screen and there is not a place to use the code.
Also my device is not listed on my Microsoft account.

Please help me, all my life is on this phone.

Comment: Can you please add more detail. Have you tried rebooting it..??

Comment: If you don't have any important data on your Phone, try hard resetting it. If you don't want to hard set your phone, you can contact online with Microsoft Answer Tech, they will definitely guide you about this. Meanwhile I will try to help you if I find a solution for this.

Comment: u mean a crying emoji with a blue background? if that's the case, you'll need to reset!